# turn off grid lines for R xyplot timeseries

Tags: r, time-series, gridlines

I am plotting a time series with the timePlot function of the open air package of R. The graph has grey grid lines in the background that I would like to turn off but I do not find a way to do it. I would expect something simple such as grid = FALSE, but that is not the case. It appears to be rather complex, requiring the use of extra arguments which are passed to xyplot of the library lattice. I believe the answer lies some where in the par.settings function but all attempts have failed. Does anyone have any suggestions to this issue?

Here is by script:

```
 timeozone <- import(i, date="date", date.format = "%m/%d/%Y", header=TRUE, na.strings="")
 ROMO = timePlot(timeozone, pollutant = c("C7", "C9", "C10"), group = TRUE, stack = FALSE,y.relation = "same", date.breaks = 9, lty = c(1,2,3), lwd = c(2, 3, 3), fontsize = 15, cols = c("black", "black"), ylab = "Ozone (ppbv)")
 panel = function(x, y) {
    panel.grid(h = 0, v = 0)
    panel.xyplot(x,y)
  }
```